# FluentValidation and collection of object its property should be unique

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have class:

```
Sponsored { int Order };
```

And I have collection of it:

```
IEnumerable<Sponsored> sponsored;
```

I want to check if `Order` is unique for this collection.

Can I do it via `FluentValidation`?

I have:

```
SponsoredValidator : AbstractValidator<IEnumerable<Sponsored>>
```

and

```
SponsoredValidator : AbstractValidator<Sponsored>
```

@Edit: 
It should be connected with WebAPI POST method via ValidationAttribute

```
[Validator(typeof(SponsoredValidator))]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public class SponsoredCollectionValidator : AbstractValidator<IEnumerable<Sponsored>>
{
    private class SponsoredComparer : IEqualityComparer<Sponsored>
    {
        public bool Equals(Sponsored x, Sponsored y) => x?.Order == y?.Order;
        public int GetHashCode(Sponsored obj) => obj.Order;
    }

    public SponsoredCollectionValidator()
    {
       RuleFor(coll => coll)
           .Must(coll => coll.Distinct(new SponsoredComparer()).Count() == coll.Count())
           .WithMessage("Elements are not unique.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What for such Guid comparer?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'Sponsored' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Sponsored]'.",

Comment: Is your base type `AbstractValidator<IEnumerable<Sponsored>>`? If it is just `AbstractValidator<Sponsored>`, then `coll` is not a collection but a single `Sponsored` instance. Where do yo get this error?

Comment: It do not modify ModelState.IsValid to false.

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` works only in MVC and you must call `FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure()` in your `Application_Start` method. Btw. I never use it. The manual way should always work: `var validationResult = new SponsoredCollectionValidator().Validate(myCollection); bool isValid = validationResult.IsValid;`

Comment: See `ValidationResult.Errors`